# Pandas Dataframe column to python list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas data frame with duplicate values and I want to convert into python list in alphabetical order.

```
print(df)
            items
0           Shoes
1           Shoes
2           Jacket
3           Basket
4           Shoes
5           Umbrella
6           Basket
7           Jacket
output=['Basket','Jacket','Shoes','Umbrella']
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Pandas DataFrame to Python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21745678/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-python-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try below code

```
output= df.sort_values(by=['items'])['items'].drop_duplicates().tolist()
```